# forEach to Join Array Items in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, foreach, concatenation

I am trying to take an array of strings, and using forEach return a single string containing all the array items. The directions specifically exclude using .join(), which would have been my 1st choice.

```
    // This is a list of words
let words = ['Loops', 'are', 'a', 'great', 'way', 'to', 'find', 'elements', 'in', 'an', 'array'];

// TODO: implement this function to return a string containing all words in a paragraph.
function createParagraph(words) {
  let paragraph = '';

  return paragraph;
}

// Prints paragraph to console
console.log(createParagraph(words));

// don't change this line
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = createParagraph;
}
```

I have tried:

```
words.forEach(words.join(' ')).push(paragraph);
```

Comment: If you are not allowed to use `join()`, you can loop over the items and each time perform `paragraph += " " + currentWord`

Comment: `words.forEach(word => paragraph += word += " ");` That worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @roninroyal_ *The directions specifically exclude using .join()* - Why ? I am just curious to know the reason.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal it's just the directions for the assignment. This is part of a class "practice." The funny thing is, when we test we used .join().

Comment: @roninroyal_ Yes got it. I added an answer as per the understanding. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `.join` is `.reduce`

here's a quick implementation:

```js
words.reduce((previous, current) => {
    return previous + " " + current
})
// will return the words with a space seperating them
```

alternatively, if you want to do this with pure forEach, you can try

```js
function createParagraph(words){
    let paragraph = '';
    words.forEach((el, i) => {
        paragraph += el
        if(i < words.length-1) paragraph += " "
    })
    return paragraph
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to convert the array into a string without help of JavaScript inbuilt methods. If Yes, Then you are good to go with the `Array.forEach` method for the iteration of an array and concatenate the elements by using arithmetic symbol.

Live Demo **:**

```js
// This is a list of words
let words = ['Loops', 'are', 'a', 'great', 'way', 'to', 'find', 'elements', 'in', 'an', 'array'];

// Function which returns a string containing all words in a paragraph.
function createParagraph(words) {
  let paragraph = '';
  words.forEach(word => {
    paragraph += (words[words.length - 1] !== word) ? word += " " : word
  });
  return paragraph;
}

// Prints paragraph to console
console.log(createParagraph(words));
```